# Can I get git fsck to show commit names?

Tags: git

I have a deleted commit, among many deleted commits, that I'm trying to restore. I found out about the fsck --lost-found command. Great!

The problem is I have over a hundred dangling commit statements with very little information.

```
dangling commit 654857f5e8418c4031e1d8411579906c528da562
dangling commit 74499bd482d688c1416d5091b391d82a438855a9
dangling commit 124ed7cd4465434865577c82757732df62febb59
dangling commit 92573bf4595be6f80f22eba94548dbc88d8796fc
dangling commit 125b0ffa3f0db71f23fda65d6adb2f9941748cc0
dangling commit ba5b1f8d6d920900abc88bd725d44ba86c8c772f
dangling blob e760d751ae4e3dab9beed0996e683c0f291eb4cc
```

If it could just throw out the commit name with the sha that would be a big help. As it is, I have to run the git show on each one, one-by-one, to find the right commit. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Feed the IDs into `git show`?

Comment: Is there a syntax I can use to automate that, or do I have to do it one-by-one?

Comment: I'm on git shell- does the OS matter? For the sake of argument I'm using Windows

Comment: To solve your actual problem, have you tried git reflog combined with git log? If the commits have been in a branch at some point in the recent past, git reflog will show the branch at that point in the past and you can try to extract the commit id from the log.

Comment: Does git shell support `grep` and `xargs`?

Comment: What do you mean by "commit name"? Commits have hashes/IDs - those are already shown in your output above. Commits don't have names...

Comment: twalberg- are you aware of the process of giving a commit a description in git? That's what I am referring to. I would argue that looking at a bunch of hashes doesn't really provide any valuable information to the user regarding the content of the commit

Comment: @IcedDante Yes, I am aware that every commit in `git` has a commit *message* attached, even if it's empty. However, that is not a commit *name* - which tends to indicate something more along the lines of a *tag* or *branch* name. Dangling commits won't have a *branch*, pretty much by definition. They *might* have a tag pointing to them, though. That's why I asked for clarification about your question - your requesting a "commit name" was not a clear requirement.

Comment: OK- I'm glad we were able to clear it up!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not an answer solving this with git fsck, but something which might work in this situation.

`git reflog` outputs a list of past HEADs in the repository. For example, if you switch from a branch master to a branch devel, this produces a reflog entry with the HEAD of the master branch.

So if the commit was part of a branch at some time, the chances are great that you can recover it using a combination of `git reflog`, `git log` and a bit of manual work.

There are a few cases:

1. Just fire up `git reflog` and scroll through it. If it shows the commit message you were looking for, that’s great! Copy the commit ID and use it for whatever you want (e.g. `git cherry-pick`, or save it into a branch using `git branch save-my-commit commitid`).
2. The commit is not directly in `git reflog`, but you see a commit which you made *after* the commit you want to find (and before deleting it). In that case, use the commit ID of the commit you made afterwards as found in `git reflog` and pass it as argument to `git log`: `git log commitid`. Scroll through the output and see if you can find your commit. Use the commit ID as in case 1.
3. The commit is not directly in `git reflog` and you do not find a commit of which you know that you made it *after* the commit you deleted and *before* deleting it.

   This is the most tedious case, in which case it *might* be easier to go through the other processes here. I am not sure though that they will actually be listed as dangling commits, so it is worth a shot if you cannot find your commit using `git fsck`.

   Go over all entries in `git reflog` and use the commit IDs as argument to `git log` as described in case 2. Try to find the commit you are after.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Jonas- the commit was easily discovered in reflog.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer, mine was case number 2.

Answer (score 20):

This works on Linux and Mac:

```
git fsck --lost-found | grep "dangling commit" | \
   cut -d" " -f 3 | xargs -I "{}" git --no-pager show --stat "{}"
```

With pager and more like `git log` (kudos to [Rafał Cieślak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/742872/rafa%C5%82-cie%C5%9Blak)):

```
git fsck --lost-found 2>/dev/null | grep "dangling commit" | \
    cut -d" " -f 3 | \
    xargs -I "{}" git --no-pager show --no-patch --format=format:"%h <%an> %s%n" "{}" | \
    less
```

I'm not sure if you have `grep` and `xargs` in the Windows git shell.

Explanation:

- `git fsck` finds the data
- `grep` reduces that to only the dangling commits
- `cut` leaves only the commit ID
- `xargs` runs the command `git show --stat` with the IDs

**[EDIT]** Fixed for cases when there are several dangling commits.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. This doesn't work in Windows Shell: I simply get a ">>" character. I believe this is related to the redirect to a text viewer. I'm trying the file redirect but that's not working either. I'll try a few other things and report back.

Comment: Here's a version which instead of using a pager for each commit, outputs all dangling commits in a specific format line-by-line and then pipes this output to `less`. As a result, the output looks more like git log. It also ignores the error messages coming from git fsck.

`git fsck --lost-found 2>/dev/null | grep "dangling commit" | cut -d" " -f 3 | xargs -I "{}" git --no-pager show --no-patch --format=format:"%h <%an> %s%n" "{}" | less`

Comment: @RafałCieślak i think you should post this as an answer;

Comment: Thanks. This really saves my day. I also create [a common use command gist](https://gist.github.com/geemaple/1e9b67ab2862f4467bf46c67a53da0e1) for later reference.

Comment: In case someone finds this question when trying to grep the output of `git fsck` and look for errors, note that you have to check stderr instead of stdout, as it won't capture the errors in stdout by default: `git fsck --no-progress 2>&1 | grep -q 'error\|fatal'`

Answer (score 0):

Or may be more simpler:

```
git fsck --lost-found | sed 's/\(dangling commit \|dangling blob \)//' | xargs -t -n1 git show
```